# Populating Combobox from a customfield list on Userstories level from Rally in wsapi

Tags: rally, wsapi

On Userstory level I have a customfield, that is a list of items. 
How can I show these customfield items in a Combobox in Javascript on my app?

[Screenprint customfield (list) on Userstory level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4NKz.png)

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

The FieldValueCombobox is generally designed for this exact purpose:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox

I'm not 100% sure it will work for multivalue custom fields though.  Perhaps if you set `multiSelect: true` in the config?

Multi-value custom fields were released after the release of App SDK 2.1, which is why there's not an out of the box component to support them.  The screenshot you linked of the detail page uses a component written in React which is not yet available in an SDK.